# Is there a way to transform a char-type vector to a numeric-type vector?

Tags: r

I have a character vector that stores numbers with 1 and 2 decimals. I would like to change it to a numeric vector that keeps all the decimals to be able to make mathematical computations with it.

```
a <- as.character(c('1,1','1,25','1,3','1,36'))
a
"1,1"  "1,25" "1,3"  "1,36"
a <- as.numeric(a)
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to replace the comma with a decimal with `gsub` and then convert it to numeric with `as.numeric`

```r
a <- as.character(c('1,1','1,25','1,3','1,36'))


as.numeric(gsub(',','\\.',a))

[1] 1.10 1.25 1.30 1.36
```

Comment: I'd recommend `sub(',', '.', a, fixed = TRUE)`. `sub` rather than `gsub` because we expect to make a single replacement per element, not multiple replacements, and `fixed = TRUE` for an exact match rather than a regex pattern, which let's us skip the `\\` escape and will be more efficient. (Not that efficiency matters here, but a good habit to form.)

Comment: Thanks! I am doing that but it returns integer numbers i.e. for 1,6, it returns 2. Why?